Long response time with llama-server (40–60sec)
I managed to run the Llama server with the following command:
./llama-server -m models/7B/ggml-model.gguf -c 2048

My request looks like this:
time curl --request POST --url http://localhost:8080/completion --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"prompt": "Can you tell me a bit about GDPR?"}'

The service response time is between 40–60 seconds regardless of the model (I tried several Llama and Vicuna models, including 7B/13B 5q). Changing the prompt also didn't make a difference. I also tried with catai/node-llama-cpp but got similar results.
Waiting for a minute for a response is not acceptable. Is this normal?

make sure that your models are loading on GPU instead of CPU. you can check nvidia-smi command to check the GPU memory usage.
